# Smooth out contour plot and add gradient arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

The code below produces contour lines of the functions `$(x,y)\mapsto e^{-x^2-y^2}$`. I would like to:

- Smooth out the contour lines. I found out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406639/smoothing-out-contourplot-in-gnuplot) whis is valid when working directly with gnuplot. However, the use of gnuplot *via* TikZ does not seem to handle the " isosamples " variable or at least I did not succeed to use it.
- Add gradient vector to visualize their orthogonality to the contour lines.

Any help would be appreciated !

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

% TikZ Figures
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,domain=-2:2,view={0}{90}] 
\addplot3 [contour gnuplot={
    labels=false,
    number=5} ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)}; 
\end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An example with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) code.

Compile on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
import graph;
import contour;

size(300,false);
pair a=(-2,-2),b=(2,2);
real f(real x, real y){ return exp(-x^2-y^2);}

// The gradient vector of f(x,y)
pair F(pair z)
{
  real x = z.x, y = z.y;
  return (-2*x*f(x,y),-2*y*f(x,y));
}
path vector(pair z) {return (0,0)--F(z);}
guide[][] g=contour(f,a,b,uniform(0,1,10),350);
guide[] G=concat(... g);
pen[] p={red, green, blue, orange, gray};
p.cyclic=true;
for (int i=0; i<G.length; ++i) draw(G[i],p[i]+0.8bp);

limits(a+(0.3,0.3),b-(0.3,0.3));
add(vectorfield(vector,a+(0.3,0.3),b-(0.3,0.3),15));
crop();
xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks(Size=4),above=true);
yaxis("$y$",LeftRight,RightTicks(Size=4),above=true);
shipout(bbox(mm,invisible));
```

[image]

Comment: Your way is okay with explicit expression of the gradient. There is another (implicit) way in here https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dgraphs/vectorfield3.asy that use `path3 gradient(pair z) {
  static real dx=sqrtEpsilon, dy=dx;
  return O--((f(z+dx)-f(z-dx))/2dx,(f(z+I*dy)-f(z-I*dy))/2dy,0);
}`